# SyntaxError: invalid syntax - Не вижу ошибки

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, syntax

```
import requests
import telebot
import json
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
# Создаем экземпляр бота
bot = telebot.TeleBot('Убрал здесь специально, в самом коде токен есть')
# Функция, обрабатывающая команду /start
@bot.message_handler(commands=["mstart"])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет, я ИИ Мико, скорее чат-бот, который много умеет и старается ради своего создателя Miko Kun (https://mikoland.tk)")
@bot.message_handler(commands=["m?"])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Напиши вопрос (либо отправь фотографию с вопросом), на который можно ответить да или нет')
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=["text", "photo"])
    def start(message):
        response = requests.get("https://yesno.wtf/api")
        s = response.text
        d = json.loads(s)
        pardon = d['image']
        pardon1 = d['answer']
        bot.send_animation(message.chat.id, pardon)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, pardon1)
@bot.message_handler(commands=["mtranslate"])
def translate(message):
    TEXT_TO_TEXT_URL = "https://fasttranslator.herokuapp.com/api/v1/text/to/text"
    LANG = "en-ru"
    TEXT = message.text
    url = f"{TEXT_TO_TEXT_URL}?source={TEXT}&lang={LANG}"
    resp = requests.get(url)
    #d1 = json.loads(resp)
    #pardon = d1['data']
    print(resp)

async def cmd_minfo(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Привет, товарищ! Я ИИ Мико - Бета-сборка 1.0. Пока вовсе недоделанная, хотя обещаю быть лучше")

# Где-то в другом месте...
@dp.register_message_handler(cmd_test2, commands="minfo")
bot.polling(non_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Сам не понимаю в чем ошибка, а выдает

```
bot.polling(non_stop=True, interval=0)
^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: убрать отступ блока с `@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text", "photo"])`

Comment: не работает, та же ошибка

Comment: После декоратора должна идти функция или класс, который декорируется, а у вас идёт непонятно что. Вы уверены, что `@dp.register_message_handler` вообще является декоратором?

Comment: На сам код он вовсе не влияет. Это я могу подтвердить, эта ошибка возникла до вступления @dp.register_message_handler в код

Comment: Все таки вы правы, andreymal.

Comment: Эмм, простите, а что вы делаете? Вы что телебот с айограмом пытаетесь связать? Зачем?

Comment: @oleksandrigo, я уже разобрался с проблемой, прошу не писать без повода.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если что, извиняюсь сразу. Я немного забыл, что поставил @dp.register_message_handler и из-за него появилась ошибка. Спасибо @andreymal!